# Vee Validate require either of two fields

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js

I'm trying to use Vee Validate to require either of two input fields, name OR location, but they cannot both be empty. I am getting this error- 'Error in directive validate bind hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'expression' of undefined"' Here's what I have-

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"> 
    <div class="same-height-parent"> 
        <div class="same-height" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('searchLocation') }"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zip or City, ST" v-model="searchLocation" v-validate ="{ rules: { required: this.locationInput} }" data-vv-name="searchLocation" > 
        </div>                                                 
        <div class="form-element same-height">or</div>                                                 
        <div class="same-height" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('searchName') }"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" v-model="searchName"  v-validate ="{ rules: { required: nameInput} }" data-vv-name="searchName"> 
        </div>                                                 
    </div>                                                                                          
</div>                                         
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"> 
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-fz20" 
    @click="validateBeforeSubmit()">Search</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
export default {
      name: 'startNewSearch',
      data: function() {
        return {
          sectionTitle: 'Start a New Search',
          sectionClass: 'search',
          searchLocation: '',
          searchName: '',
          searchType: 'location'
        }
      },
      methods: {
        validateBeforeSubmit: function(e) {
          this.$validator.validateAll();
            if (!this.errors.any()) {
              this.submit()
          }
        },
        submit: function(e) {}
    }    
  },
  computed: {
    locationInput() {
        if(this.searchName === '') {
          return true; 
        }
        return false;
    },
    nameInput() {
        if(this.searchLocation === '')
            return true; // cellphone is required
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but I came across it while looking for a similar problem.

Anyhow, I believe you have a syntax error.

```
v-validate ="{ rules: { required: nameInput} }"
```

...you're missing 'this'...

```
v-validate ="{ rules: { required: this.nameInput} }"
```

Regards,

Wayne

Answer (score 2):

In vee-validate v3 my solution was to extend the `require_if` rule like this:

app.html:

```
...

<ValidationProvider name="lastName" immediate rules="required_if_not:company" v-slot="{ errors }">
...
```

app.js:

```
extend('required_if_not', {
    ...required_if,
    // params: ['target']
    validate: (value, args) => {
        let target_value = args.target;
        return Boolean(target_value || value);
    },
    message: 'Bitte dieses Feld ausfüllen.'
});
```

this also works with multiple fields.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I'm using an valdiation-observer with v-slot="{invalid}" ; and this is used within the submit-button :disbaled="invalid". Unfortunately, for the first time, invalid is true until the fields are hit for the first time. Do you know a solution for that?